# Transition FPS Camera Animation from Idle to Walking?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I recently learned how to animate certain objects, but I don't know how the code works.

I learned the animator tab, where idle camera animation will transition from walking if I am holding my movement keys. I searched tutorials on youtube and google, but all I can find are animations found on models, not actually on the camera.

If I used that logic on a camera, nothing actually happens, and I don't know what to write.

I've set a bool, which is labeled "WalkingForward", because I have different animations on different movements.

When it is true, the forward walk animation will play, and if false, it turns back to idle animation.

The only thing I can't figure out is a code that will detect the "Horizontal" and "Vertical" movements to start playing the animation.

Here is the link of my animator controller tab https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGAZm.jpg , and I would really appreciate if someone has an idea.

Comment: What is moving horizontally/vertically? The player or the camera or both? Where are you trying to detect the movement?

Comment: It actually needed to detect the default unity "horizontal" and "vertical" button holds, like the WASD. Thanks for the quick response, it really was a rookie mistake, a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle/detect movement in the `Update()` method for a `GameObject`, then get the `Animator` for the Camera and set the Animator parameters.

See [Unit Animation Parameters Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) for more info, but the general idea is something like this:

```
// Update method attached to wherever you want to detect movement
void Update()
{
    // isMovingHorizontally and iMovingVertically are not defined here
    // They could either be based off the speed/momentum of the GameObject
    // Or the input from the player 
    var isMovingHorizontally = isMovingHorizontally();
    var isMovingVertically = isMovingVertically();
    
    animator.SetBool("MovingHorizontally", fire);
    animator.SetBool("MovingVertically", fire);
}
```

Comment: Goodness! I thank you for the fast response. I actually had the same idea, but the bool I typed in the code was SUPPOSED TO CASE SENSITIVE. It was actually my own fault. I appreciate your help.